# Remedy or remedies

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

Dictionaries say the word "remedy" is a countable noun. I found phrases "access to remedy" and "access to effective remedy" without an article in the text of the UN Guiding Principles on Business and Human Rights." For example, "Access to effective remedy has both procedural and substantive aspects." Could anyone explain why the word is used as an uncountable noun?  I can google the expression "access to remedies" in English-language posts. Are both correct?

Comment: The idea that a noun is either count or non-count must be eradicated. _I love coffee; it's my favourite drink. In fact, I had two coffees before showering today._ It's **usages** (in sentences) that are count or non-count. Many nouns can be used both ways. // Yes, 'remedy' is used in both count and non-count (eg 'used in the effective remedy of ...')  ways, as your (correct) examples illustrate. 'Remedy' in the example here means 'putting right / curing' rather than 'effective medicine / other prescribed technique'.

Comment: *Remedy* is its sense of *redress* — which is how it is used in your example — is uncountable. Look up *redress* to compare.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is believing dictionaries that say the word "remedy" is a countable noun (although, in fairness, it does not say it is **only** a countable noun).

The uncountable "remedy" is not common and usually refers to the class of of legal actions that will correct an injustice. Nouns are not usually "only countable" or "only uncountable": "countability" is an attribute that can change.

> THE Supreme Court's momentous decisions last week on affirmative action, voting rights and same-sex marriage overshadowed a disturbing trend: in the final two weeks of its term, the court ruled in favor of big business and closed the courthouse doors to employees, consumers and small businesses seeking **remedy** for serious injuries. (New York Times)
>
> In response to their claims, insurance companies formed a posse with their friends in government and are spending their time and resources trying to prevent victims and their families from seeking **remedy** for their pain, instead of accepting responsibility, paying their debt to society, and changing their ways. (Huffington Post